# Webdriver is Not able to read element-Null Pointer exception..

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am Trying to Automate a Test sequence of Login - Booking - Cancellation.
Till Booking its Fine , But moment it Reaches Cancellation, It throws a java lang Null-Pointer Exp.
I rechecked and My locators(xpath) is correct(xpath-Checker) and I am Trying to getText() the Ticket Number and proceed to cancellation.

Problem is whenever WebDriver is reaching the Booking confirmation Page , which Loads after a While, it Fails and Returns Null Pointer Exp..

It may be a Loading Issue which is handled or I am messed up with my Java Concept...

Please Help !! anyone...

```
public class StackOverflow { 

       public static  WebDriver driver;
       public static  Properties p;
       public static  FileInputStream f ;          

 @Test
        public void loginTest()  {
            System.out.println("Enter Login");
        Properties p=new Properties();
        FileInputStream f = null;
        try {
            f = new FileInputStream("D:\\BOSSFramework\\Framework\\locators.properties");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            p.load(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://in3.seatseller.travel/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();


        try{
            driver.findElement(By.name(p.getProperty("login.username.textfield"))).sendKeys("UserName");
            driver.findElement(By.name(p.getProperty("login.password.textfield"))).sendKeys("Password");
            WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("login.signin.button")));
            ele.click();            
                }
             catch (Exception e) {                  
                }           
        }

@Test (dependsOnMethods={"loginTest"})
        public void booking() throws InterruptedException{
            System.out.println("Enter Booking");
            // Type Bangalore on Source Field.. 
            Properties p=new Properties();
            FileInputStream f = null;
            try {
                f = new FileInputStream("D:\\BOSSFramework\\Framework\\locators.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                p.load(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.source.textfield"))));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.source.textfield"))).sendKeys("Bangalore");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.source.textfield"))).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                Thread.sleep(900L);         

                // Type Mysore on Destination Field             
                WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.destination.textfield"))));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.destination.textfield"))).sendKeys("Tirupathi");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.destination.textfield"))).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);     

  }
@Test (dependsOnMethods={"booking"})

              public void cancellation() throws InterruptedException{
                  System.out.println("Enter Cancellation");               
                    WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
                    Thread.sleep(9000);
    /*Facing Null Pointer Exp  Here */                  
                    wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.congratulations.text"))));
                    wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.congratulations.text"))));
                    Thread.sleep(9000);
   /*Facing Null Pointer Exp  Here  */                  
                    WebElement ticket =driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.ticket.text")));   
   /*Want to getText() Ticket Number to cancel*/
                    String ticket1 = ticket.getText();
                    System.out.println(ticket1);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.leftNavCancel.link "))).click();                 
                    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.phoneNumber.textfield"))));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.phoneNumber.textfield"))).sendKeys(TIN1);                 
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.search.button"))).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("oneapp.cancel.button"))).click();  
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the line, from above code, for which the error `null pointer exception` is thrown?

Comment: Add complete stacktrace

Comment: You forgot to initialize `p` in third method.

Comment: Yes I have Edited and added the Required Properties File to the 3rd Method, and it worked Fine... THANKS ALL >>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add `Properties p=new Properties();` in your `cancellation()` method or mention it outside of the test methods(In the begining, you've declared `public static  Properties p;` rather define it there like `public static  Properties p = new Properties();`)

Answer (score 0):

In first two methods you create `f = new FileInputStream` but in the third method you read properties without it. Did you try to read properties again?